# Simulating key press and/or instantiating forms.button

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WPF app I'm trying to create a button that depresses with a key stroke using button.performclick but im not sure how to instantiate and add a forms.button to my UI. Currently I am using controls.button if there would be a way to do it with those that would be much simpler for me.
here is what i was trying to do:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Button ButtonA = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
beatGrid.Children.Add(ButtonA);
```

but i get this error:
the best overloaded method match for 'system.windows.control.uielementcollection.add(system.windows.uielement)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: you are mixing up `winforms` stuff and `wpf` stuff :))) What UI tech are you using? It should be `wpf` or `winforms` although we can take some interoperability between them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `WPF` but don't know the actual class of `Button` in WPF, here it is:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Button ButtonA = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
```

However you should use `XAML` code for UI setup. Because it's optimized to use in `XAML` and procedural code will become awkward.

### UPDATE

To click a Button programmatically in `WPF`, we have to use `Automation` which is a little tricky. Try this extension method for convenience:

```
public static class ButtonExtension {
  public static void PerformClick(this Button button){
    var buttonPeer = new System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
    var invoker = buttonPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    invoker.Invoke();
  }
}
//Usage
yourButton.PerformClick();
```

I hope you understand how to use `extension method`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using WPF, but the problem is the controls button doesnt have the functionality that I need, thats why I want forms.button

Comment: @user2998100 what functionality?

Comment: I want to use button.performclick() so that i can stimulate a button click from a key press

Comment: Im actually pretty new to c# I have not used extension methods, if it's not to much to ask could you explain how I implement that?

Comment: @user2998100 you just need to copy the static class I posted in the update and paste in **the outermost namespace**, don't add it in any other class. Then call the extension method normally.

Comment: ok cool a couple more things, several of those things were unrecognized, what namespaces does that require, and can you explain this (this Button button)

Comment: @user2998100 you should place the static class in the same namespace with your form class (otherwise you have to use `using yourNamespace;` at the beginning of your file to use the extension. For the `this Button button`, it's the syntax to define an extension method, it helps us distinguish the normal method and the extension method, the extension method needs to reference the instance and this instance is passed in as the first **special** argument. When you use the extension method, you don't need to pass in this first special argument.BTW **Please search for extension method** to learn it

Comment: Yeah I read the MSDN on extension methods and will continue to look at it, should (this Button button) be controls or forms button?

Comment: @user2998100 the extension method supports only `Button`, so you can't use Control instead, the code inside uses `ButtonAutomationPeer` so it works only for `Button`, for other control you may have to look at other `Automation peer`. However I'm not sure you can programmatically click other control in the same way.

Comment: It tells me that its ambiguous what kind of button its using

Comment: @user2998100 please remove your `System.Windows.Forms.dll` reference or remove `using System.Windows.Forms;`, or **explicitly** write `System.Windows.Controls.Button` in your code. I'm **TOO** tired answering some very basic problem to you.